# How can I install and use the additional Asian fonts included in iOS 6?

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uifont

I'm writing an iOS 6 iPhone/iPad app that needs to display Chinese characters. The Asian fonts installed by default in iOS 6 leave a lot to be desired. However, at the bottom of [Apple's iOS 6: Font List page](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5484), Apple states that:

> "Apps can also install the following [mostly Asian] fonts as necessary."

The Asian font families don't appear in the list provided by `[UIFont familyNames]`. I haven't found any information in the UIFont class documentation or on the Apple Developer Forums about how to install a font that is, presumably, already included in iOS 6 but not yet "installed." Any ideas?

Comment: Fascinating question! I'm dying to know the answer now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- You **can't** change the global font in iOS.
- Some of this list are **already "installed"** and appear in `[UIFont familyNames]` (e.g. Apple SD Gothic Neo)
- Every iOS App is able to add custom fonts which aren't supported, yet (e.g. BiauKai)
- There are **no** API diffs from 5.1 to 6.0 in `UIFont.h`
- There are **no** API diffs in `UIFont.h` since 4.0 (added lineHeight, deprecated leading).

---

> "Apps can also install the following [mostly Asian] fonts as necessary."

Since we know every developer can use custom fonts it's absolutely no problem to add them or "install" them for your app.

I'm pretty sure these are some requested fonts, which some guy at Apple wrote on this page to show that it's possible to use these fonts nevertheless even if they are not specially supported by iOS.

---

*I know this is no answer which is totally correct or totally wrong - it's based on the information I knew and I found on the web and makes it clear, that we probably never know the answer.*

---

To support a custom font add your font in a `.ttf` format to your project (**and to your target** - I forgot this more than once!) and add it to your **Info.plist**. Now it's possible to use it with `someLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MySuperFont" size:100];`

Comment: I saw this list soon after the iOS6 announcement when they said they've added more Asian languages support, so I presumed they were not installed by default because they are quite large in size but an application could trigger the download. But you are probably right.

Comment: ... but font support isn't the same as language support. From the view of Apple the only logical relation is the font-support in Safari. But since `@font-face` everything is possible here too.

Comment: Completely correct solution. If you want a special font just download the .ttf from the many font sites or use https://github.com/nathanhammond/iosfont to download and place them in your Xcode Project.

Comment: Indeed you can install any custom font, I was just wondering why would Apple in "Apps can also install the following fonts as necessary" specify only a short list of Asian fonts. Are these fonts included in OS X and they are the only difference in fonts between iOS and OS X?

Comment: In fact, this is what I've done. The fonts are installed by default on OS X (I'm using 10.8 Mountain Lion). I simply copied them into my app bundle, added them to my Info.plist, and can now access them fine in the app. Like you, Fabio, I'm guessing/hoping that Apple's assurance that we can "install the fonts as necessary" means that we are licensed to use them in this manner in our iOS apps. I guess I'll know for sure when I submit the app.

Comment: @Vincent e.g. BiauKai is a difference between iOS and OS X - but the font "Apple SD Gothic Neo" is already included in iOS.

Answer (score 2):

> "Apps can also install the following [mostly Asian] fonts as
>   necessary."

It is about legal and operational *issues*. These fonts are (co?-)licensed  under Apple and available in Mac OSX. If you want to use them you can include them in your project by using a copy from the OSX /Library/Fonts folder in your iOS bundle **without infringing the copyright** of the respective font owner.

Furthermore: they are compatible with iOS 6 (e.g. passing the Font Validation int the Font Book app), you might be aware that there are many free asian fonts out in the wild but are not working 100% on iOS 6 and it is frustrating to try them all out; licenses for professional asian fonts are quite expensive.

To install the desired font use "Font book", determine the font you like, open in finder (it might be a fontname with ideograms, just go ahead), copy the font into your project and use as reference to the font the font name and not the filename. Be sure to update the `UIAppFonts` (Fonts Provided By Application) items in your info.

Example: Kaiti font on Mac OSx is  `楷体.ttc` and preparing your project as explained will enable you to create UIFont with name `@"Kaiti SC"`.

One last point: you should NOT publish on github or similar a public project that contains these fonts.

Answer (score 0):

If you download any font you like to your mac and install it. It will appear in Xcode like below:

[image] [image] [image]

Comment: It will work in the Interface Builder but it won't work on iOS, because you haven't added it to your target.

Comment: @Fabio Poloni - Ah right. You also need to add the font to the frameworks folder in the project

Comment: Add it to your project. Add it to your target (or it won't be available). Add it to your Info.plist. Then everything should work ;)

Answer (score 0):

i also wanted to add extra fonts in my project at a time.... so...

check this out

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NSuSDuoyfh4

Answer (score -1):

The iOS supports adding custom fonts in an iOS application.
Here is a sample explaining how you can do that.

http://www.mobilefontfonts.com/use/ios

Comment: This is definitely NOT what he asked.